# Is there a name for the factorization $\frac12(a+c)(b-d)+\frac12(a-c)(b+d)=ab-cd$?

Tags: terminology, factoring

I came across this factorization:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac12 (a + c)(b - d) + \frac12 (a - c)(b + d) &= \frac12(ab-ad+cb-cd+ab+ad-cb-cd)
\\[4pt]
&= \frac12(2ab - 2cd) \\[4pt]
&= ab - cd
\end{align}
$$

Is there a technical mathematical name for this? I've seen it briefly being referred to as "twisted factorization" but it doesn't seem prevalent.

Comment: For $c=d$ it's very useful in SOS (Sum Of Squares method for inequalities proofs).

Comment: Is there a common name for this identity?

Comment: I named it searchlight, but it's known for my students only.

Comment: @slaw: What made you think that this has a specific name?

Comment: @Bumblebee I figured that if there were common knowledge then there would be some consensus as to how to refer to this

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the name, but this follows from the factorization of matrices: $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}\frac{a+c}2&\frac{b+d}2\\-(a-c)&b-d\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}\frac 12&\frac 12\\ -1&1\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}a&d\\ c&b\end{array}\right].$$ Geometrically, this can be explained as follows: Let $v_1=<a,d>,v_2=<c,b>$ be two vectors. Then $$v_1\wedge v_2=\frac 12(v_1+v_2)\wedge (v_2-v_1),$$ i.e. the area of the parallelogram spanned by $v_1,v_2$ is half of the area of the parallelogram spanned by the vectors representing the diagonals of the previous parallelogram.

Answer (score 1):

One way to view this identity is as saying that $A = \begin{pmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2} & \frac1{\sqrt2} \\ -\frac1{\sqrt2} & \frac1{\sqrt2} \end{pmatrix}$ defines a unitary operator on $\mathbb R^2$, for the standard inner product. Since, when $v = (a, -c)^t$ and $w = (b, d)^t$, the LHS expresses $\langle Av, Aw \rangle$ and the RHS expresses $\langle v, w \rangle$.

Comment: I’m looking for the common technical name for this factorization as I would like to perform a Google search and learn more